# Why HTTP/2 on a specific site works in FF, but doesn't work in Chrome, IE and Edge on the same Windows 10 computer?

Tags: windows, http, nginx, browser, https

I have a site, that runs on a Nginx 1.10.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 server (OpenSSL 1.0.2h). I want to serve this site over HTTP/2, so I configured Nginx accordingly:

```
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server
```

And it works fine in FF 47 and Chrome 51 on my office Ubuntu 15.10 desktop and in the same browsers on my home Ubuntu 15.10 desktop.

However on my home Windows 10 desktop and laptop HTTP/2 works only in FF. Chrome 51, IE 11 and Edge are using HTTP/1.1 on this site.

So, I'm baffled. [This service](https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test) says, that my site supports HTTP/2 and ALPN (which is required for HTTP/2 to work in Chrome [since version 51](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/transitioning-from-spdy-to-http2.html)).

Chrome versions and capabilities are exactly the same:

[image: Chrome Network Info]

HTTPS works, and Security panel in Chrome Dev Tools shows, that everything is secured.

[This demo](https://http2.akamai.com/demo) in Chrome, IE and Edge displays message "*This browser is not HTTP/2 enabled.*", and "*Your browser supports HTTP/2!*" in FF.
But HTTP/2 on [medium.com](https://medium.com) works just fine in all of this browsers.

So, my question is: what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Having the same issues, Chrome was working on H2 a couple of weeks ago, seems some build/update might have broken it?

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk but why medium.com works in Chrome and Edge and IE and my site doesn't? But works in FF and Chrome on Ubuntu... It puzzles me - some mix of server, browser and OS issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using antivirus software (e.g. Avast) and is it inspecting your HTTPS traffic?

It does this by acting like a MITM so you connect it it and it connects to the real website. And if they only support http/1 (which as far as I know they only do) then that would explain this. Though oddly not for for Medium unless you have an exception for this.

Should be easy enough to check by looking at the HTTPS cert when visiting the site to see if it was "issued" by your local Avast server.

If not that then suggest you look at your ciphers as HTTP/2 is picky about which ones it uses. Anything weird showing on https://www.ssllabs.com/servertest for your site? What cipher is it using for Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed my NOD32 antivirus messing with my traffic: Chrome shows ESET certificate for my site, but original for medium.com. I don't have any exceptions set up, it's all default settings, since I never thought about this feature. I will contact my antivirus support to clarify this behaviour. Thanks for your response, it was very helpful.

Comment: Np. It's catching a few people out and there's a few questions on here about that that I would have linked to but the Medium thing threw me (and still does!) so wasn't 100% convinced it was that.

Comment: I confirm this problem happened to me too with NOD32. I've removed it and now http2 is enabled. Thank you for your help.