# HTTP2 doesn't work on Nginx 1.10.1, Openssl 1.2.h and Chrome 51.0.2704.103

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration, http2

I generate a SSL certificates with compile-installed openssl-1.2.h (But I install the openssl-devel with yum). And here's my nginx(1.10.1) configuration.
    server {
    charset utf-8;
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  localhost;

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/aa_2048.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/aa_2048.key;

#
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/private/aa_2048.dhparam;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";
keepalive_timeout 70;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m; 
...
}
```

I use chrome 51.0.2704.103 to open the link but it uses http/1.1 protocol instead of http/2.x that I suposed.
So what's wrong with it?

Here's the process of openssl and nginx.  --> https://github.com/AarioAi/Conf/tree/aario/Dockerfiles    Not the master branch, but the branch aario.

[image]

[image]

[Here's the process of openssl and nginx.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsMok.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why HTTP/2 on a specific site works in FF, but doesn't work in Chrome, IE and Edge on the same Windows 10 computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368099/why-http-2-on-a-specific-site-works-in-ff-but-doesnt-work-in-chrome-ie-and-ed)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368099/why-http-2-on-a-specific-site-works-in-ff-but-doesnt-work-in-chrome-ie-and-ed/38411249#38411249

Comment: I'm using win10, but I didn't install any virus-anti softwares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you compile Nginx using openssl 1.0.2h or only use that to generate the cert csr?

Can you edit your question to add the output of "nginx -V" ?

Guessing it was compiled using openssl 1.0.1 and Chrome requires openssl 1.0.2 or above as it needs ALPN (https://ma.ttias.be/day-google-chrome-disables-http2-nearly-everyone-may-31st-2016/).

If HTTP/2 works for other browsers (e.g. Opera or Firefox) then that'll be the reason why.

Comment: Here's the configurations of Openssl (in CentOS Container), Nginx ...  https://github.com/AarioAi/Conf/tree/aario/Dockerfiles    --> PS: Aario branch, not the master branch. Obviously, it's Nginx 1.10.1 and openssl 1.0.2h

Comment: I see no mention of openssl in that link. Can you run the "nginx-V" command and post results as requested?

Comment: I re-edited the question. And you'll see the nginx -V there.

Comment: Yup built with OpenSSL 1.0.1. Http/2 won't work with Chrome unless you use OpenSSL 1.0.2 as stated in my answer. Read the link given.

Comment: Oops, thanks a lot. I'll try to specify the --with-openssl to the 1.0.2h

Comment: Gah! Goooogle!!! *shakes fist* I was having the same problem, Firefox and Safari used HTTP/2, while Chrome 51 and 52 did not. Thanks for the info!