# Latest Nginx with OpenSSL 1.0.2 still won't deliver http/2

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration, http2, lets-encrypt

I have a server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Nginx 1.112 built with OpenSSL 1.0.2h, and according a number of HTTP/2 support verficiation tools, like [this one](https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test), the server is properly configured for HTTP/2 with ALPN.  Yet in the latest Chrome (51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)), a reqest to the server returns with protocol `http/1.1` and not `h2`:

[image: chrome still delivering http/1.1]

I've read a number of posts here, like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/775298/debian-jessie-nginx-with-openssl-1-0-2-to-use-alpn-rather-than-npn) noting that Nginx built with OpenSSL versions pre 1.0.2 do not support ALPN.  But I am running 1.0.2h.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial 

$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.11.2
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
TLS SNI support enabled

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

Qualys SSL Labs 'SSL Server Test' gives the domain an A+ SSL rating.  I used Let's Encrypt to create the cert, via the method referenced [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Could it still be an Nginx certificate configuration issue?

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all that, I was able to discover that it was a local issue.  My antivirus application, [Avast Mac Security](https://www.avast.com/en-us/free-mac-security), was preventing the protocol upgrade. Disabled it, and h2 is used.

[image]

[BazzaDP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144578/bazzadp)'s answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368099/why-http-2-on-a-specific-site-works-in-ff-but-doesnt-work-in-chrome-ie-and-ed) is what led me to discovery:

[Why HTTP/2 on a specific site works in FF, but doesn't work in Chrome, IE and Edge on the same Windows 10 computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368099/why-http-2-on-a-specific-site-works-in-ff-but-doesnt-work-in-chrome-ie-and-ed)